# How to put notification after specific time

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alarms

Need help for putting a notification after a specific time, have seen couple of examples here but it is not working for me.

On button click a method is called to set the AlarmManager with 5 seconds from now which in turn should call my method to put notification.
below is the code for the same.

```
private void startAlarm() {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
         long when = rightNow.getTimeInMillis()+5000;

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RemainderService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,when,pendingIntent);
    }
```

From another class (file) RemainderService.java

```
public class RemainderService extends IntentService {
    public RemainderService() {
        super("RemainderService");
    }

    private static final int NOTIF_ID = 1;

    @Override
      protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();         // notification time

        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "reminder", when);
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.flags |= notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Notify.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("notificationID", 20);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 20, notificationIntent , 0);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "It's about time", "You should open the app now", contentIntent);

        nm.notify(NOTIF_ID, notification);
    }
}
```

---

Basic human error, forgot to add  details in manifest file.

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly? Please be more explicit.

Comment: Notification does not get triggered when i try this code, looks like alarm is not getting triggered after set time of 5 seconds.